# Eclipse C builder doesn't compile pre-built files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, prebuild

In my Eclipse project there is a `pre-build.bat` script that generate interface C files from JSON. The generated files are cleared during `clean`. They are stored in `/${ProjName}/${ConfigName}/protocols`.

The problem is that the build system doesn't *see* the generated files after a clean build. The `pre-build.bat` runs fine, but the IDE or some reason doesn't *refresh* the list right after `pre-build` step so the new files are not compiled. Running the build second time builds fine.

I've tried adding a simple "Builder" to force the refresh, but it refreshes *after* the build.

Is there any way to either force the refresh after pre-build step or force the refresh in the `pre-build.bat` or manually add the names of the files that will be generated into the list of sources?

Eclipse Version: 4.21.0.v20210906-0842